# Safely set a STRING variable in hive?

Tags: bash, hive, environment-variables, hiveql

## Problem

I can set variables in hive at run time:

```
$ cat my_query.sql
select '${hiveconf:my_string_variable}'
$ hive -f my_query.sql -hiveconf my_string_variable=foobar
```

(returns)

```
foobar
```

But if I run the query and forget to set the variable (no `-hiveconf` argument), hive treats the call signature as a string:

```
$ hive -f my_query.sql
```

(returns)

```
${hiveconf:my_string_variable}
```

## Desired Result

I want it to give an **error** (for trying to reference a variable that does not exist).

I understand this doesn't happen because my "variable" is just treated as a string. So, I'm looking for some other way to pass a string when the variable is set, but error out when it doesn't exist.

---

## I've tried:

### Checking Variable Is Set Before Using It

```
$ cat my_query2.sql
set my_variable; --hoping this errors out when hive realizes it's undefined
select '${hiveconf:my_string_variable'
$ 
$ hive -f my_query2.sql
```

(returns)

```
my_variable is undefined
OK
${hiveconf:my_string_variable
```

### Using Another Data Type

I can make this "work" if the string can be interpreted as an Int literal:

```
$ cat my_query3.sql
select cast(${hiveconf:my_string_variable} as string)
$ 
$ hive -f my_query3.sql --hiveconf my_string_variable=1234
```

(returns)

```
1234
```

But it fails as soon as I put a real string in it:

```
$ hive -f my_query3.sql --hiveconf my_string_variable=foobar
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 1:12 Invalid table alias or column reference 'foobar': (possible column names are: )
```